# Strange Situation | You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a strange situation. I have this code:

```
$dispnam = strtoupper($display_name);
$data = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("dbname");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT location FROM upload WHERE name = '".$dispnam."'")
or die(mysql_error());  
$check = mysql_num_rows($data);
$info = mysql_fetch_array($data);
$display_url = $info['location'];
echo $display_url;
```

which returns an error 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HIGHLIGHT'>BATMAN_SLAPPING_ROB' at line 1'

I have no idea where have I gone wrong. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks iin advance!

Comment: Echo out your SQL. You'll have an apostrophe in it; this is one of the reasons why binding variables is a good idea.

Comment: $dispnam returns that only.

Comment: Returns _what_, exactly?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Someone commented here and delete it, my previous comment was for him. Sorry. Alright so how do I do that? like echo SELECT location FROM upload WHERE name = '".$dispnam."' ?

Comment: @Albab - that should do it.

Comment: That is siply echoing the statement... didn't fixed. And $dispnam contains ~ BATMAN_SLAPPING_ROBBIN

Comment: Then something else in your code is going wrong, because the word HIGHLIGHT isn't in there. Are you certain that it's that piece of code is failing? How are you generating `$display_name`? Is this code run in a function? A loop? What are the inputs? Does it run once? Multiple times?

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). Read a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) to avoid making mistakes like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I understand that and I appreciate your help. But I had to fix it for someone so I cannot change anything I just have to fix it.. Also, I got the solution. I was fetching data from $data and the query was made from $result so I had to change the $result to $data and it worked like charm. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

$dispnam seems to contain a single quote. You should be using a parametrized query instead of constructing your query from strings

Comment: $dispnam contains this value ~ BATMAN_SLAPPING_ROBBIN

Comment: can you please give an example?

Comment: @Albab: According to your error message, `$dispnam` contains this: `HIGHLIGHT'>BATMAN_SLAPPING_ROB`

Comment: Example and explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: I got the solution. I was fetching data from $data and the query was made from $result so I had to change the $result to $data and it worked like charm. Thanks for your help :)